# Rails dynamically create model and use it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I am creating a model whose name is the input argument in a rake task. After the rake task, I wish to use the model to insert data.

So for example, I call my rake task with input Apple and the model Apple is created. Then I wish to do `Apple.insert_all([{name: x},{name: y}...])` in another rake task but I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Apple`

Here's a better picture of the flow of what I'm doing

```
Rake::Task["create:fruit"].invoke("Apple") # create model here
Rake::Task["create:insert"].invoke("Apple") # insert data here but getting error
```

This is how I process the input in the second rake task:

```
task :insert, [:name] do |t, args|
    fruit = args.name 
    fruit.classify.constantize.insert_all(xxx)
end
```

Any suggestions for how to go about this?

Comment: I doubt it is feasible. Still check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: why do you need rake for this? why can't you use standard rails migration? this seems like an anti-pattern IMHO.

Comment: Creating migrations/models is a manual task, I am trying to automate creating migrations with a rake task. I have successfully done this already. I just need to insert data into the created model for a test and am trying to use Rails 6 `insert_all` instead of executing a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and tried your code. I think the problem is in this line

```
fruit.classify.constantize.insert_all(xxx)
```

The code bellow works and create new records. I use a simple `rake` command to run it.

`create.rake` file

```
namespace :create do
  desc "TODO"
  task :insert, [:name] do |t, args|
    klass = Object.const_get(args.name)
    klass.create([{name: 'x'},{name: 'y'}])
    p klass.count # testing new records have been saved
  end
end
```

`Rakefile` file

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks

task :default do
  Rake::Task["create:insert"].invoke("Apple")
end
```

Comment: strange, I still get the same error. Maybe it is because I am running the two raske tasks in an rspec test?

Comment: What is the purpose of your rake tasks?
Do you want just to seed your DB to run tests?

Comment: The purpose of my rake task is to create models dependent on specifications. I read specification files and create models based on them, the rake task creates the migration dynamically. Meaning if you have files with table schemas, you can feed it to the rake task and it will create tables for you

Comment: I can still create a SQL string and execute the SQL via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` but I want to utilise Rails 6 `insert.all` if possible

Comment: @Ayudh can you replace dynamic class with simple `Apple.insert_all` call? I'm sure models must be accessible from both rake and rspec

Comment: No, as I get the error, besides, I'd like to abstract away the model name so that it can be run for other models

Comment: I understand, it is just for testing purposes. If it works then the problem with dynamic class creation. Otherwise it's about the model not being loaded into the environment.

Comment: stay tuned, I am finishing up the project and will update this question a bit later